# Lawn mower's power line cut off caused partial power outage

Tags: powertools

I happen to cut off lawn mower's power line with the lawn mower cross over it to cause partial power outage. Everything seems to be OK except the outlets on the exterior of the house. I checked my fuse box, and nothing is on off side.

How can I turn it on again? If I need professional services, to whom do I ask help?

Comment: LOL. Sorry but we've done this before...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exterior outlets are normally GFCI protected either at the breaker box or the outlet itself. If you have checked at the box already, check that none of the outlets is a tripped GFCI. If it is, there is a reset button on it.